# How to use API write the result of tokenization into a txt file

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have already found some code to show the result, but i do not know how to write them into a txt file, because the type HasWord can not be written into a file or translated into String type.

```
DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor("myorigin.txt");
for (List<HasWord> sentence : dp) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sentence.size();i++){
        HasWord S= sentence.get(i);
        System.out.print(sentence.get(i));
        System.out.print('|');
    }
    System.out.println(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class TokensWriterExample {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0])), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output_file.txt", "UTF-8");
        for (CoreLabel cl : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            writer.println(cl);
        }
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Make sure you get Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 from here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml